# State is not set after useEffect in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the next component in my react application:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import AsyncSelect from "react-select/async";
import { ColourOption, colourOptions } from "./docs/data";

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setState(colourOptions);
  }, []);

  return (
    <AsyncSelect
      cacheOptions
      defaultOptions
      loadOptions={async () => new Promise((r) => r(state))}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

There i set `colourOptions` in useEffect and after that i read the `state` in `loadOptions`. Now the options don't appear when i open the select, but when i change `loadOptions={async () => new Promise((r) => r(state))}` to `loadOptions={async () => new Promise((r) => r(colourOptions))}` the dropdown items appear. 
 How to make my code workable in the first situation with `state`, using `useEffect`? 
 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-b3857?file=/example.tsx:355-409

Answer (score 4):

The thing is, state *is* set after the useEffect call (to test this, just map the state in the JSX and log each array index). The `loadOptions` function in `react-select`'s async component [appears](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/packages/react-select/src/useAsync.ts) to be memoized with only its props as dependencies, so you're not going to get a new `loadOptions` function just because you've set the state in your `useEffect`. In other words, upon a new render of your component the options will stay the same even though state has been updated. The question is, why use `useEffect` at all?

It seems to me like you're calling `useEffect` in your example to simulate an asynchronous call, like you'd do when you want to fetch some data. Normally, when people want to fetch data, they'll throw the async call into a useEffect and fetch the data after the first render. The thing is, the `loadOptions` function exposed by `react-select`'s async component *already provides this functionality* - that is, it will fetch your options for you asynchronously at first blush right when you need them, rather than wait an extra step for a state update that may force you to programmatically re-instantiate the `loadOptions` function (by changing a prop like `defaultOptions` or something [possibly even more hacky](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1879).

TLDR just use the `loadOptions` function as your asynchronous data fetcher rather than wait for `useEffect`.

Comment: the idea is that i can not use a `state` created with useState hook inside `loadOptions`,if that state is updated with useEffect, but i need to use state there. How to do that? I

Comment: Hi @Asking, in that case, as my answer describes, go ahead and try passing the `state` value as `defaultOptions` - this way, you are telling the component that it should rerender once state has been loaded from your useEffect. I think you'll discover that this has its own set of drawbacks, though I'm still unclear on what exactly you're trying to accomplish. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the state is asynchronous it means you can not get its value immediately after you set the state.

So this problem can be fixed by initializing state.

```
const [state, setState] = useState(colourOptions);
```

Comment: i need the solution with useEffect because `colourOptions` could be different on first render and useEffect is realy important here. Do you have a solution for that?

Answer (score -1):

Since the state setting is asynchronous you can try adding a loading screen while the options state remains undefined,something like

```
return (
{state?
    <AsyncSelect
      cacheOptions
      defaultOptions
      loadOptions={async () => new Promise((r) => r(state))}
    />
:
<SomeLoadingScreen/>
}
  );
```

Comment: there is a diferent issue, your answer does not work

Comment: what is the specific issue then,if i know it i can try to help @Asking